# Problems with the list<> C# component

Tags: c#

I have a List<itemgridvenda> from an Items class

The class

```
public class itemgridvenda
    {
        public int Codigo { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public string Unitario { get; set; }
        public string Valor { get; set; }
        public string Categoria { get; set; } 
        public decimal Quantidade { get; set; }
    }
```

I use this list to fill a DataGridView, with everything, when I double click on a line of my Grid, I need the item to be deleted from the list and the grid to be updated.
But I am not able to remove the item from the list.

In the CellDoubleClick action I made this code

```
 private void dgvItens_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {         
            string texto = "Deseja excluir o item" + dgvItens.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value + " do pedido?";
            var result = MessageBox.Show(texto, "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (Convert.ToString(result) == "Cancel") { return; }
            else
            {
                dadositemvenda.Remove(new itemgridvenda() { Codigo = Convert.ToInt32( dgvItens.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value), Descricao = Convert.ToString(dgvItens.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value), Unitario = Convert.ToString(dgvItens.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value), Valor = Convert.ToString(dgvItens.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value), Categoria = Convert.ToString(dgvItens.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value), Quantidade = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvItens.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value) });


                dgvItens.DataSource = null;
                dgvItens.DataSource = dadositemvenda;
                dgvItens.Refresh();
                decimal valor = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvItens.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value);
                removevalorgrid(Convert.ToDecimal(valor));
            }
        }
```

However, the Remove() function in the list is not being able to delete my new element.
I already checked and the parameters of the Grid's idex are in correct order.

Would there be an easier and more correct way to delta this item from the list and update the grid later?
Because the way this doesn't work.

Comment: `.Remove` requires that you remove the same object, not just one that looks similar. You need to find the actual item's position and remove that. Perhaps `dadositemvenda.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);`

Comment: I understand, it would be because of New, in the case I create a new object, how would I go about locating exactly the object I need?

Comment: You can use the `RemoveAll` method to remove items that match specific criteria. That would allow you to specify property values to match against.

Comment: I did some tests here and I understood, thank you very much the solution for this case was

 dadositemvenda.RemoveAll(itemgridvenda => itemgridvenda.Codigo == Convert.ToInt32(dgvItens.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value));